# p:overlayPanel Full Screen

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I'm developing a SW application and between de transition of two pages xhtml pass several seconds. I'm trying to put a `p:overlayPanel` which hide full screen with a gif and its almost working. the problem is that, despite of the fact I'm including top,bottom,left and right 0 ! important, there is a big padding and I cant fit the panel properly.

Could please someone help me??

Here is my code,

```
<p:overlayPanel id="moviePanel" for="btn_alta" dynamic="true"  appendToBody="true"  style="transition:10s;background: #FFF;Opacity: 0.5;left:0 !important;right:0 !important;top:0 !important;bottom:0 !important;width:100%; height:100%; z-index: -1;  position: fixed ;overflow:hidden">
    <p:graphicImage value="/resources/img/loading_comments.gif" width="150" style="top:50%;bottom:50%;left:50%;right:50%;position: fixed"/>

    </p:overlayPanel>
```

Comment: On what component is the padding?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!!
    <h:form id="formMenu">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li><h:commandLink  action value="Alta" id="btn_alta"/></li>   
   <li><h:commandLink action="salir" value="Salir" /></li>   
  </ul>

Comment: The paading is in the overlaypanel

Comment: So if the padding is IN the overlay panel, then it does fit full screen, right? What is the problem then?

Comment: I want the overlaaypanel covers the full screen, and despite of the fact i modified de top,left,right,and bottom properties of the overlaypanel to 0 important! i have a left and top padding of 200 px more or less so the overlay panel doesnt hide all the buttons of my screen, and im not able to fix the problem of push other buttons while the next screen is loading, that is what i was looking fo. I cant attach a photo of the properties but the pannel appears with:

top: 251.266px
left: 161 px

I dont understand you can see my code, im modifying this properties.

Anyway thank u very much

Comment: Solved using AjaxStatus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897415/can-use-ajaxstatus-while-the-next-page-is-loading?noredirect=1&lq=1