# Can use AjaxStatus while The next Page Is Loading?

Tags: javascript, java, primefaces

Im developing a SW Application. I have been for several time trying to show a modal between the transition of my xhtml pages. I dont want the user can push many buttons or repeat pushing while the next screen is loading.

First i tried it putting an overlayPaneltrying to cover the full screen but i found this problem:

[p:overlayPanel Full Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642500/poverlaypanel-full-screen)

Then, I tried it using blockUI blocking the whole body of my page, but then I found this other problem:

[p:blockui disable ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764750/pblockui-disable-ajax)

Finally, I really thought that i got it, using a JS function but then I had this problem (basically the problem is that it dont works with the dataTable):

[onstart and oncomplete dont work in datatable with p:commandLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874366/onstart-and-oncomplete-dont-work-in-datatable-with-pcommandlink)

Thank U In Advice!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make an ajaxStatus try to make it like that (do not forget that the ajaxStatus is invoked each time you use a `p:ajax` that mean in your dataTable you need to add an ajax event when you try to invok it )

***mypage.xhtml***

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()" />
<h:form id="form">
...
 </h:form>

 <p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
        <p:graphicImage name="ajaxloadingbar.gif" library="images/myIcons" />
    </p:dialog>
```

Hope that helped you

Comment: Thank u the problem here is that i got templates and lots of mini xhtml pages: template.xhtml left-menu.xhtml header.xhtml list.xhtml. Should I have to write down de <p:dialog> and the <p:ajaxStatus>  in each place that i have a form? What happends if I have many buttons or links in my form and my page have a lot of forms?

Comment: yes you have to write  it in every xhtml page and about the forms your page contain one master form you put it there

Comment: SOLVED!!!! WITH P:COMMANDLINK MY OWN ICONS AND THE MODAL LOADING!!!! tHANKS A LOTTTTTT @Yagami Light

Comment: Yo only have to put it once in your page. I just put it in the header once and it works for the whole page. Thanks again @Yagami Light

Comment: @Pilar i told you you can do it